# Retrieve scrape urls from text file in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following script and I would like to retrieve the URL's from a text file rather than an array. I'm new to Python and keep getting stuck!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
urls = ['URL1',
        'URL2',
        'URL3']
for u in urls:
   response = requests.get(u)
   data = response.text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
```

Comment: Have a look into it, https://stackoverflow.com/a/3277516/4985099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please be a little more clear about what you want?

Here is a possible answer which might or might not be what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
with open('yourfilename.txt', 'r') as url_file:
   for line in url_file:
      u = line.strip()
      response = requests.get(u)
      data = response.text
      soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'lxml')
```

The file was opened with the `open()` function; the second argument is `'r'` to specify we're opening it in read-only mode. The call to `open()` is encapsulated in a `with` block so the file is automatically closed as soon as you no longer need it open.
The `strip()` function removes trailing whitespace (spaces, tabs, newlines) at the beginning and end of every line, for instant `'  https://stackoverflow.com   '.strip()` becomes `'https://stackoverflow.com'`.